# Do not apply any other shopping cart price rule if a particular shopping cart rule is applied

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart

I have a promotional offer of 5% when a combo of two products is bought together. I also offer an additional offer of 5% when the customer subscribes to the newsletter. But i want some customization in this.

The customization goes like: 
I do not want to allow any other shopping cart price rule when the promotional offer of 5% is allowed on cart.

I have overriden the `Mage_SalesRule_Model_Validator` class, but it doesnt help me.

Can anyone guide me.?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a shopping cart price rule you have a flag called `Stop further rules from processing`.
Set that flag to `yes` and set the priority of the rule to `0` (zero). Make sure that all the other rules have the priority 1 or more and it should work without any code changes.

Comment: sorry my mistake, the promotional offer is not a shopping cart rule

Comment: then what is it?

Comment: Its an extension that provides the discount on bundled products.

Comment: Then you should contact the extension developer.